# Get codes for lowered forms in the same data.table: Faster implementation wanted

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `x` with approx. 2M rows and 2 columns: `entry` and `code`. `entry` contains character values that *might* be repeated elsewhere in `entry` in lowered form. Also, all-lower entries exist, that do not have a non-lowered form. Each row in `x` has a unique code in column `code`. I've created a reproducible example with only 6 rows.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(entry = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ddd"),
                code = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
x
   entry code
1:   Aaa    1
2:   Bbb    2
3:   Ccc    3
4:   aaa    4
5:   bbb    5
6:   ddd    6
```

As you can see, `Aaa` and `Bbb` also come with their lowered "counterparts" `aaa` and `bbb`. `Ccc` does not have a lowered form and `ddd` does not have a non-lowered form.

I now want to assign a new column `low_code` which holds the code for the lowered counterpart if there is one. If not, the code should remain the same. This is what my goal would look like in this example:

```
   entry code low_code
1:   Aaa    1        4
2:   Bbb    2        5
3:   Ccc    3        3
4:   aaa    4        4
5:   bbb    5        5
6:   ddd    6        6
```

As you can see, the codes for `aaa` and `bbb` get assigned for `Aaa` and `Bbb`. For `Ccc`, there is no lowered version, so the code remains the same.

What I have done so far is this (and this works):

```
x$low_code <- sapply(x$entry, USE.NAMES = F, FUN = function (e) {
  low_e <- tolower(e)
  ret <- x[x$entry == low_e,][["code"]]
  if (length(ret) == 0) { # If no low entry is found... 
    ret <- x[x$entry == e,][["code"]] # ...return original code
  } 
  stopifnot(length(ret) %in% c(0, 1)) # Too many return values (should never happen)
  ret
})
```

However, it is extremely slow for my original data.table with more than 2 million rows. I suspect this is due to the indexing for every single entry (`e` in the code above).

I would be *very* surprised if there isn't a considerably faster option (maybe leveraging data.table syntax) but I am out of ideas. Any help is much appreciated - if you have the time, please also explain your solution with a few words so I can learn from it. As always, I hope that I didn't overlook any answers solving a similar problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following?

```
rows = grep("^[A-Z]", x$entry)
x[(rows), lentry := tolower(entry)]
x[(rows), low_code := x[(-rows)][.SD, on = .(entry = lentry), x.code]]
rm(rows)
x[, lentry := NULL]
x[is.na(low_code), low_code := code]

#     entry  code low_code
#    <char> <num>    <num>
# 1:    Aaa     1        4
# 2:    Bbb     2        5
# 3:    Ccc     3        3
# 4:    aaa     4        4
# 5:    bbb     5        5
# 6:    ddd     6        6
```

Comment: That's working, thank you. Timing: 6.65s mean, 6.59s median (10 microbenchmark runs)

Comment: @swolf is that good enough you were hoping for something faster?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(entry = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ddd"), code = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
x[, low_entry := tolower(entry)
  ][entry == low_entry, low_entry := NA]
x[x, low_code := i.code, on = .(low_entry == entry)
  ][, low_entry := NULL
  ][, low_code := fcoalesce(low_code, code)]
x
#     entry  code low_code
#    <char> <num>    <num>
# 1:    Aaa     1        4
# 2:    Bbb     2        5
# 3:    Ccc     3        3
# 4:    aaa     4        4
# 5:    bbb     5        5
# 6:    ddd     6        6
```

This should work even if there are multiple lower `entry` values. For instance,

```r
x <- data.table(entry = c("Aaa", "Bbb", "Ccc", "aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "aaa"), code = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
x[, low_entry := tolower(entry)
  ][entry == low_entry, low_entry := NA]
x[x, low_code := i.code, on = .(low_entry == entry)
  ][, low_entry := NULL
  ][, low_code := fcoalesce(low_code, code)]
x
#     entry  code low_code
#    <char> <num>    <num>
# 1:    Aaa     1        7   # <-- reflects the _last_ `"aaa"` found
# 2:    Bbb     2        5
# 3:    Ccc     3        3
# 4:    aaa     4        4   # <-- own `code`
# 5:    bbb     5        5
# 6:    ddd     6        6
# 7:    aaa     7        7   # <-- own `code`
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Timing: 8.04s mean, 8.07s median (10 microbenchmark runs)

Answer (score 1):

*merge* full dataset with all lower-case subset, non-matches NAs get updated with existing *code*:

```
merge(x[, .(rn = 1:.N, entry_low = tolower(entry), entry, code) ],
      x[ tolower(entry) == entry, .(entry_low = entry, code_low = code)], 
      by = "entry_low", all.x = TRUE
      )[ is.na(code_low), code_low := code 
         ][ order(rn), .(entry, code, code_low)]
#    entry code code_low
# 1:   Aaa    1        4
# 2:   Bbb    2        5
# 3:   Ccc    3        3
# 4:   aaa    4        4
# 5:   bbb    5        5
# 6:   ddd    6        6
```

Comment: Thank you, it also works! Timing: 11.05s mean, 10.97s median (10 microbenchmark runs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original data.table untouched this might help.

- first generate the `tolower` grouping entries,
- then select the corresponding *code* values and
- last put code for `NA` values if no grouping was found.

```
x[, .(code, entry, l_entry = tolower(entry))
  ][, .(entry, code, low_code = ifelse(
    any(l_entry == entry), last(code[l_entry == entry]), code)), by = l_entry
  ][, .(entry, code, low_code)]
   entry code low_code
1:   Aaa    1        4
2:   aaa    4        4
3:   Bbb    2        5
4:   bbb    5        5
5:   Ccc    3        3
6:   ddd    6        6
```

If more lower entries (e.g. *aaa*) with different values are present it takes the `last` one. Can be changed to `first`, too.

Comment: Thanks to you, too. It works with some warnings ("Item 2 of j's result for group 236 is zero length. This will be filled with 2 NAs to match the longest column in this result. Later groups may have a similar problem but only the first is reported to save filling the warning buffer.") Timing: 19.86s mean, 19.46 median (10 microbenchmark runs)

Comment: @swolf Thanks for sharing! The warning happened when there were more then one non-matching elements. Results were correct though. Changed code to handle that case without warning! Could even run faster now :)